# Haskell "otherwise" pattern match?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have the following code:

```
swapInPairs :: [a] -> [a]
swapInPairs [] = []
swapInPairs [x] = [x]
swapInPairs (x:y:ys) = y : x : swapInPairs ys
```

is there any way to do something like

```
swapInPairs :: [a] -> [a]
swapInPairs (x:y:ys) = y : x : swapInPairs ys
otherwise = id
```

I know it's not really a big deal, and only gets rid of one line of code, but I'm curious if there's something like this for pattern matching since guards have "otherwise".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pattern matching in general gets applied sequentially.

So if you have a 'catch-all' version *after* a more specific pattern, more specific pattern will get matched first, and if it's impossible, a 'catch-all' will do its thing.

So you can do

```
swapInPairs :: [a] -> [a]
swapInPairs (x:y:ys) = y : x : swapInPairs ys
swapInPairs x = x
```

Comment: Yep! I figured it out right after I posted it, but I'll probably end up accepting your answer just because I like `ide-haskell` a lot :p. Thanks for working on it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out order matters in pattern matching, and I didn't know that:

```
swapInPairs :: [a] -> [a]
swapInPairs (x:y:ys) = y : x : swapInPairs ys
swapInPairs x = x
```

works.

Comment: I know it took me 1 minute after asking the question to figure this out, but since [haskell otherwise pattern match](https://www.google.com/search?q=haskell+otherwise+pattern+match&oq=haskell+other&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j0l3.1382j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turns up nothing definitive on google I figured I shouldn't delete my question.